# Nested JSON object parsing using GSON

Tags: json, parsing, object, nested, gson

I have a nested JSON object like

```
{
  "hours": {
    "Friday": {
      "close": "21:00",
      "open": "11:00"
    },
    "Tuesday": {
      "close": "21:00",
      "open": "11:00"
    }
  },
  "open": true,
  "categories": [
    "Fast Food",
    "Restaurants"
  ],
  "city": "Dravosburg",
  "review_count": 7,
  "name": "Mr Hoagie",
  "neighborhoods": [

  ],
  "longitude": -79.9007057,
  "state": "PA",
  "stars": 3.5,
  "latitude": 40.3543266,
  "attributes": {
    "Take-out": true,
    "Drive-Thru": false,
    "Good For": {
      "dessert": false,
      "latenight": false
    },
    "Caters": false,
    "Noise Level": "average",
    "Takes Reservations": false,
    "Delivery": false,
    "Ambience": {
      "romantic": false,
      "intimate": false,
      "classy": false
    },
    "Parking": {
      "garage": false,
      "street": false
    },
    "Has TV": false,
    "Outdoor Seating": false,
    "Attire": "casual"
  },
  "type": "business"
}
```

I am using GSON to parse this json object. I have created POJO classes as below:

```
 public class BusinessPojo {

   private String type;
   private String name;
   private ArrayList<String> neighborhoods = new ArrayList<>();
   private ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
   private BusinessDay hours = new BusinessDay();
   private String city;
   private boolean open;
   private String state;
   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;
   private float stars;
   private int review_count;
   private BusinessAttributes attributes;
//getters and setters
}
public class BusinessDay {
    private BusinessHourTime monday = new BusinessHourTime();
    private BusinessHourTime tueday = new BusinessHourTime();
    private BusinessHourTime wednesday = new BusinessHourTime();
    private BusinessHourTime thursday = new BusinessHourTime();
    private BusinessHourTime friday = new BusinessHourTime();
    private BusinessHourTime satday = new BusinessHourTime();
    private BusinessHourTime sunday = new BusinessHourTime();
// getters and setters
}
public class BusinessHourTime {
    private String open;
    private String close;
//getters and setters
}
```

and similarly for `Attributes`, inside Attributes for `Parking`, `Ambience` and `GoodFor`. This is my code:

```
String line = "json object"
Gson g = new Gson();
BusinessPojo businessJsonObj = g.fromJson(line, BusinessPojo.class);
```

When I try to access `"Drive-Thru"` like

```
System.out.println(businessJsonObj.getAttributes().isDriveThru());
```

I get value `false`, however when I try to access  `open` from `Friday` or `Tuesday` I get `null` like

```
System.out.println(businessJsonObj.getHours().getTuesday().getOpen());
```

Could anyone help me understand what mistake have I done in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The given JSON has some issues from the stylistic point of view. And this should be considered for GSON mapping. By default, GSON maps DTO classes field names to JSON field names "symmetrically" (getters and setters are ignored): if your top-most class field is named `foo`, then the given JSON should contain the top-most field named `foo` as well in order to be mapped with the default rules.

However, GSON features a name overriding mechanism with the [`@SerializedName`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation. In your case, it should be:

```java
public static final class BusinessDay {
    ...
    @SerializedName("Tuesday")
    private BusinessHourTime tueday = new BusinessHourTime();
    ...
```

And the use case (assuming static nested classes with access to the fields directly for simplicity):

```java
System.out.println(businessJsonObj.hours.tueday.open);
```

> 11:00

Similarly, I'm assuming, your `isDriveThru()` will never work for `true` always returning `false` regardless the JSON, because of a name `Drive-Thru` that starts with a capital letter (and it doesn't really matter if your mapping class field starts with `D` as well) and contains a hyphen `-` in its name. Since the latter hyphenized naming issue are disasallowed in Java, you have to map the field explicitly as too:

```java
@SerializedName("Drive-Thru")
private boolean isDriveThru;
```

Also, if possible, I would strongly recommend to fix the JSON property names in order to get rid of non-standard naming: merely camelCase for JSON property names, like `Friday` -> `friday`, `review_count` -> `reviewCount`, `Take-out` -> `takeOut`, `Good For` -> `goodFor`, and so on. Having the format fixed, you'd not need `@SerializedName` annotations for the most cases (also note the typos like `tueday` for `tuesday`, `satday` for `saturday`, etc). If it's not possible, just use this annotation to fix the mappings as described above.